# Azure TableClient ConnectionString update_request TypeError on dict

Tags: python, azure, exception, entity, azure-table-storage

I'm creating the table client like so:

```py
with TableClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_string, table_name=self.table_name) as table_update_entity:
    table_update_entity.update_entity(_entity, mode = UpdateMode.REPLACE)
```

The `_entity` variable is a dictionary build like so:

```py
_entity = {
    str: str,
    .
    .
    .
    str: str,
    str: dict # This dict build is shown below
}
dict = {
    str: str,
    str; str,
    str: str,
    str: list,
    str: list,
    str: list
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> <class 'TypeError'>
>
> Type not supported when sending data to the service: <class 'dict'>.

I've been trying to fix it for the past few hours, tried google, tried chatGPT and no luck for now, no solution I found help.

---

Currently the only way I managed to "do it" is by deleting the request and then recreating it from 0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below sample code to create an entity in Azure Table Storage with a nested dictionary.

**Code:**

Below is the code for REPLACE mode,

```py
import json
from azure.data.tables import TableClient, UpdateMode

class AzureTableUpdater:
    def __init__(self, connection_string, table_name):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.table_name = table_name

    def update_entity_with_nested_dict(self, entity):
        partition_key = entity['PartitionKey']
        row_key = entity['RowKey']

        nested_dict = entity.pop('nested_data')
        nested_dict_json = json.dumps(nested_dict)

        entity['nested_data'] = nested_dict_json

        with TableClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_string, table_name=self.table_name) as table_client:
            table_client.update_entity(entity, mode=UpdateMode.REPLACE)

connection_string = "<connec_string>"
table_name = "<table_name>"

entity = {
    'PartitionKey': '<Partition_Key>',
    'RowKey': '<Row_Key>',
    'property1': 'value1',
    'property2': 'value2',
    'nested_data': {
        'nested_key1': 'nested_value1',
        'nested_key2': 'nested_value2',
    }
}

table_updater = AzureTableUpdater(connection_string, table_name)
table_updater.update_entity_with_nested_dict(entity)
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

***The entities created in my Azure table storage in the Azure portal like below,***

[image]

Comment: What is it `AzureTableUpdater`? and can you try with the `REPLACE` mode please?

Comment: @DolevMitz **AzureTableUpdater** is a custom Python class that encapsulates the functionality related to updating entities in Azure Table Storage. This class provides a structured and modular way to update entities with nested dictionaries in your Azure Table Storage.

Comment: @DolevMitz Can you check the updated answer for **REPLACE** mode?